# Units Tests Coverage is not updated after analysis - MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.0.2

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube

After I did an analysis of my .Net/C# project using MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.0.2, I'm able to get all the values in my SonarQube Dashboard except for the Unit Tests Coverage, which is still being shown as 0.0%.

Here's the environment I'm using...
Visual Studio 2015
MSTest
MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.0.2

The following commands were executed from Developer Command Prompt for VS2015

> path=%path%;C:\SonarQube\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.0.2
>
> MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner begin /k:tp /n:TestProject /v:1.0  /d:sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths="C:\SonarQube\Temp\VisualStudio.coverage.xml"
>
> Msbuild
>
> "%VSINSTALLDIR%\Team Tools\Dynamic Code Coverage Tools\CodeCoverage.exe" collect /output:"C:\SonarQube\Temp\VisualStudio.coverage" "%VSINSTALLDIR%\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" "C:\Projects\TestProject\TestProject.Test\bin\Debug\TetProject.Test.dll"
>
> "%VSINSTALLDIR%\Team Tools\Dynamic Code Coverage Tools\CodeCoverage.exe" analyze /output:"C:\SonarQube\Temp\VisualStudio.coverage.xml" "C:\SonarQube\Temp\VisualStudio.coverage"
>
> MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner end

I would appreciate any help in resolving this.

Comment: could you send this C:\SonarQube\Temp\VisualStudio.coverage.xml file as well as the logs produced during the "end" phase of the MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner ?